# Architecture with Api

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

i would like to ask a question, what is the best architecture to implement in a website a component to communicate with the api in svelte : Set all function related to api inside a store or with nested component with an Api component on top of each component that need data from API?

Thanks for the answer

Comment: This depends on where you need the data. If you need it in multiple components, i would recommend a store. An API component doesnt make much sense, but you could create a library for your API. So in the end you could have one or multiple .js or .ts files which handle all your API connections and perhaps even offer a store.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.